# bash watch command with colors preserved

Tags: linux, bash, watch

From `man watch`:

> Non-printing characters are stripped
>   from program output.  Use "cat -v" as
>   part of the command pipeline if you
>   want to see them.

So how do I use `cat -v` if I want to see the colored output from:

```
watch ls -al --color
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The right command is

```
watch --color "ls -a1 --color"
```

It isn't documented in the man page or the --help screen. I has to use strings to find it.

Comment: @PawełGościcki Nevermind, already found it on gitorious, although, couldn't get it to work with phpunit.

Comment: My watch is v0.3.0 and I'm on Ubuntu 10.0

Comment: I've also version 0.3.0 and for simple "ls --color" the watch command will work but for some reason more complex scenarios do not: `watch --color "sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Quality|ESSID' | egrep --color -i 'foobar|$'"`will eat the colors :(

Comment: @math: Try swapping your single and double quotes.

Comment: The `watch` from procps (the default on most Linux distros, I believe) has a `--color` option since V3.3.2.

Comment: Note that the version 3.3.2 is only available in procps-ng, original procps.sf.net seems development has stopped years ago (version is still 3.2.8 and watch version 0.2.0). Also note to OSX/Darwin users the new and maintained fork of procps-ng doesn't yet compile on OSX using LLVM (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/20845).

Comment: How do you update your watch version?

Comment: It's documented in the man page & help screen of 3.3.16 that I got from Homebrew on macOS (`watch --version` => `watch from procps-ng 3.3.16`).  `watch --help` => `-c, --color  interpret ANSI color and style sequences`.  Guessing they must have updated the documentation in newer versions.

Comment: For WireGuard's `wg` command, use `watch --color WG_COLOR_MODE=always wg show`

Answer (score 33):

I think it may not be possible with the 'watch' command. Here is a longer way of doing it:

```
while true; do clear; date;echo;ls -al --color; sleep 2; done
```

You could put this in a script, for example:

```
echo "while true; do clear; date;echo;\$*;sleep 2; done" > watch2
chmod +x watch2
./watch2 ls -al --color
```

---

To clarify, here's why I think it's not possible with the 'watch' command. See what happens if you use cat -v:

```
watch "ls -al --color|cat -v"
```

It shows you the color control characters...which I think is not what you want.

Comment: `man watch` clearly suggests that it should be possible without dissing `watch`.

Comment: It doesn't say you will be able to see colors. It says you will be able to see the non-printable characters. Try my command as above with `cat -v` to see what `man watch` was talking about.

Comment: OK. It seems I must accept the fact that it's simply impossible.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the blinking that results from the cycles of clear and print operations, a behavior not present in the `watch` command?

Comment: You can reduce the duration of the blink a little by a) collecting the data to be displayed into a variable, b) clearing the screen, c) printing the variable.

Comment: @NickRusso thanks for the suggestion. Something like this greatly reduces the flickering: `while true; do out=$(date;echo;ls -al --color);clear;echo $out;sleep 2;done`

Comment: Also consider trimming line length to fit in terminal: https://superuser.com/a/58812/114579

Comment: @KevinMark: You should use quotes to handle multiple lines: `echo "$out"`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/2414150/86967

Comment: @nobar You're right. Looks like it needs quotes in bash not not zsh.

Comment: @KevinMark You can put the "clear" command inside the parentheses. It just prints a terminal control code. See also my longer answer https://superuser.com/a/1270584/21952.

Comment: This'll blink for short intervals.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me with commands like `gh pr status` to monitor checks status from the command line.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a Mac, like me, `watch` from Homebrew does not support colour.

What you want is [fswatch](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch) but it's not Homebrew yet. To install it you'll want to do the slightly more convoluted

`https://raw.github.com/mlevin2/homebrew/116b43eaef08d89054c2f43579113b37b4a2abd3‌​/Library/Formula/fswatch.rb`

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807906/590767) for usage.

Comment: This only works for the filesystem, while `watch` applies to a command

Comment: fswatch is available on Homebrew 0.9.5

Comment: The Homebrew version of watch now supports color using the `--color` flag mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/211590/110370).  `watch --version` => `watch from procps-ng 3.3.16`.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Turns out the latest versions of `watch` fixed the problem. So, if the colors of `watch --color` are wrong, it's probably better to just update it (on my system, it's in the `procps` package).

---

The color support in `watch --color` is limited in my experience (though sufficient for `ls -l --color`). Here's my version of @davr's answer with some extra features, most importantly reduced flicker. You can put it in your .bashrc and use it as `cwatch ls -l --color`.

```
# `refresh cmd` executes clears the terminal and prints
# the output of `cmd` in it.
function refresh {
  tput clear || exit 2; # Clear screen. Almost same as echo -en '\033[2J';
  bash -ic "$@";
}

# Like watch, but with color
function cwatch {
   while true; do
     CMD="$@";
     # Cache output to prevent flicker. Assigning to variable
     # also removes trailing newline.
     output=`refresh "$CMD"`;
     # Exit if ^C was pressed while command was executing or there was an error.
     exitcode=$?; [ $exitcode -ne 0 ] && exit $exitcode
     printf '%s' "$output";  # Almost the same as echo $output
     sleep 1;
   done;
}
```

You can also try things like

```
cwatch 'ls -l --color | head -n `tput lines`'
```

if your terminal has fewer lines than the output. That only works if all the lines are shorter than the terminal width, though. The best workaround I know for that is:

```
cwatch 'let lines=`tput lines`-2; ls -l --color | head -n $lines'
```